# Exponentiation a matrix by itself N times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication, exponentiation

I am realizing Exponentiation of a matrix using FOR:

```
import numpy as np
fl=2
cl=2
fl2=fl
cl2=cl
M = random.random((fl,cl))
M2 = M
Result = np.zeros((fl,cl))
Temp = np.zeros((fl,cl))
itera = 2
print('Matriz A:\n',M)
print('Matriz AxA:\n',M2)

for i in range (0,itera):
    for a in range(0,fl):
        for b in range (0,cl):  
            Result[a,b]+=M[a,b]*M[a,b]
            temp[a,b]=Result[a,b]
            Res[a,k]=M[a,b]
print('Potencia:\n',temp)
print('Matriz:\n', Result)
```

The error is that it does not perform well the multiplication in `Result[a,b]+=M[a,b]*M[a,b]` and when I save it in a temporary matrix to multiply it with the original matrix, it does not make the next jump in `for i in range (0,itera):`

I know I can perform the function `np.matmul` 
but I try to do it with the FOR loop

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPQDJ.png)

Comment: But here you use a *numpy* array for matrix multiplication? Numpy has support for matrix multiplication, even for matrix powers.

Comment: As for why this probably does not work: you never reset `Res`, nor do you assign `Res` back to `M` after a multiplication.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [`np.linalg.matrix_power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html).

If you're using `numpy`, don't use a for loop, use a vectorized operation.

```
arr = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))

np.linalg.matrix_power(arr, 3)
```

```
array([[ 1680,  1940,  2200,  2460],
       [ 4880,  5620,  6360,  7100],
       [ 8080,  9300, 10520, 11740],
       [11280, 12980, 14680, 16380]])
```

Which is the same as the explicit multiplication:

```
arr @ arr @ arr
```

---

```
>>> np.array_equal(arr @ arr @ arr, np.linalg.matrix_power(arr, 3))
True
```

---

***Since you asked***

If you really want a naive solution using loops, we can put together the pieces quite easily. First we need a way to actually multiple the matrices.  There are options that beat n^3 complexity, this answer is not going to do that.  Here is a basic matrix multiplication function:

```
def matmultiply(a, b):
  res = np.zeros(a.shape)
  size = a.shape[0]

  for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
      for k in range(size):
        res[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]

  return res
```

Now you need an exponential function.  This function takes a matrix and a power, and raises a matrix to that power.

```
def loopy_matrix_power(a, n):
  res = np.identity(a.shape[0])
  while n > 0:
    if n % 2 == 0:
      a = matmultiply(a, a)
      n /= 2
    else:
      res = matmultiply(res, a)
      n -= 1

  return res
```

In action:

```
loopy_matrix_power(arr, 3)
```

```
array([[ 1680.,  1940.,  2200.,  2460.],
       [ 4880.,  5620.,  6360.,  7100.],
       [ 8080.,  9300., 10520., 11740.],
       [11280., 12980., 14680., 16380.]])
```

Comment: i know `np.linalg.matrix_power`  ... but I'm trying to do everything with For cycle...

Comment: @Pedro Why? That's the _opposite_ of what you want to do with numpy

Comment: @Pedro - If you want to do it by hand, you can always use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).  It's a much faster algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems here:

1. you do *not* reset the `result` matrix after multiplication is done, hence you keep adding more values; and
2. you never assign the `result` back to `m` to perform a *next* generation of multiplications.

## *Naive* power implementation

I think it is also better to "encapsulate" matrix multiplication in a separate function, like:

```
def matmul(a1, a2):
    m, ka = a1.shape
    kb, n = a2.shape
    if ka != kb:
        raise ValueError()
    res = np.zeros((m, n))
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            d = 0.0
            for k in range(ka):
                d += a1[i,k] * a2[k,j]
            res[i, j] = d
    return res
```

Then we can calculate the power of this matrix with:

```
m2 = m
for i in range(topow-1):
    m = matmul(m, m2)
```

Note that we can *not* use `m` here as the only matrix. Since if we write `m = matmul(m, m)`, then `m` is now `m`<sup>`2`</sup>. But that means that if we perform the multiplication a second time, we get `m`<sup>`4`</sup> instead of `m`<sup>`3`</sup>.

This then produces the expected results:

```
>>> cross = np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,0], [1,0,1]])
>>> matmul(cross, cross)
array([[2., 0., 2.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [2., 0., 2.]])
>>> matmul(cross, matmul(cross, cross))
array([[4., 0., 4.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [4., 0., 4.]])
>>> matmul(cross, matmul(cross, matmul(cross, cross)))
array([[8., 0., 8.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [8., 0., 8.]])
```

## *Logarithmic* power multiplication

The above can calculate the *M<sup>n</sup>* in *O(n)* (linear time), but we can do better, we can calculate this matrix in *logarithmic* time: we do this by looking if the power is `1`, if it is, we simply return the matrix, if it is not, we check if the power is even, if it is even, we multiply the matrix with itself, and calculate the power of that matrix, but with the power divided by two, so *M<sup>2 n</sup>=(M×M)<sup>n</sup>*. If the power is *odd*, we do more or less the same, except that we multiply it with the original value for *M*: *M<sup>2 n + 1</sup>=M×(M×M)<sup>n</sup>*. Like:

```
def matpow(m, p):
    if p <= 0:
        raise ValueError()
    if p == 1:
        return m
    elif p % 2 == 0:  # even
        return matpow(matmul(m, m), p // 2)
    else:             # odd
        return matmul(m, matpow(matmul(m, m), p // 2))
```

The above can be written more elegantly, but I leave this as an exercise :).

Note however that using numpy arrays for scalar comuputations is typically *less* efficient than using the matrix multiplication (and other functions) numpy offers. These are optimized, and are *not* interpreted, and typically outperform Python equivalents significantly. Therefore I would really advice you to use these. The numpy functions are also tested, making it less likely that there are bugs in it.